# How to programatically call jquery datepicker select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I simply want to call jquery datepicker `onSelect` callback as if user selected a date manually.

I initialize like the following:

```
startDateTextBox.datepicker({
       onSelect: function() {

            //callback when user selects a date

       },
       ..., //some other options

});
```

I've tried `startDateTextBox.datepicker("setDate","10/12/2012" );` but it doesn't call `onSelect` function.

An ugly hack is fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `onSelect` handler to a higher scope and call it from both places:

```
var onSelectHandler = function () {
    //callback when user selects a date
};

startDateTextBox.datepicker({
       onSelect: onSelectHandler
       ... //some other options
});

// wherever you need to programatically set the date
startDateTextBox.datepicker("setDate","10/12/2012" );
onSelectHandler.call(startDateTextBox);
```

You may need to pass some other parameters to `onSelectHandler` depending on what you use inside the function.